# Multiple Elasticsearch connections in a program

Tags: java, elasticsearch, resthighlevelclient

I was working on a service in which I get a searchHit from elastic cluster A and then use a field obtained from A to fetch details from elastic cluster B. I have created a class ClientFactory, which creates ES client based on values that I send. (A's or B's) But after getting details from A, I'm not able to create connection to B. I can either fetch details from A or B at one time. Any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two `resthighlevelclient` one which talks to `cluster A` and another which talks to `cluster B` , below is the sample code to show :

**Create client A**

```
 RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClientA = new RestHighLevelClient(
                RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(configuration.getClusteAConfig().getHost(),
                        configuration.getClusteAConfig().getPort(),
                        "http")));
```

**Create client B**

```
 RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClientB = new RestHighLevelClient(
                RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(configuration.getClusteBConfig().getHost(),
                        configuration.getClusteBConfig().getPort(),
                        "http")));
```

**You should have 2 configurations for cluster A and B, which is read by client creation code.**

```
ClusterA:
  host: cluste A hosts
  port: 9200

ClusterB:
  host: cluste B hosts
  port: 9200
```

Comment: Just a stupid doubt. Won't same port affect the connection?

Comment: it's a different cluster so same port on different host won't affect each other as port is specific to a host(node) and in your case its different cluster all together.

Comment: @NipunSoni also it would be great if you can upvote and accept the answer, as it solves the issue.